# ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion request

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I always encounter this error

> ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion request

when I am sending a `byte[]` of image from stream to my `OracleDB`.

I even change the parameter direction to InputOutput but I still encountered it.

Help here is my code.

```
public void AddUser(string userFName, string userLName, byte[] userImage)
{
    GetConnection();

        try
        {
            using (oraConn)
            {
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = oraConn;

                cmd.CommandText = "SP_ADD_USERINFOS";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("PFIRSTNAME", OracleType.VarChar).Value = userFName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("PLASTNAME", OracleType.VarChar).Value = userLName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("PIMAGE", OracleType.Blob).Value = userImage;
                cmd.Parameters["PIMAGE"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(dSet);
                
            }
            oraConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

I already change the parameter direction. It supposed to send the `byte[]` to my `OracleDB` blob column and when it already sent there. I am supposed to view the image.

Comment: Why are you using a data adapter in that case? Is there a `SELECT` statement in your sproc? You don't appear to be using the result set if there is one so `ExecuteReader` would be more appropriate and `ExecuteNonQuery` if there's no result set at all.

Comment: I don't use Oracle much but, if it were SQL Server, I'd be specifying a size for those parameters based on the column size. Should you be doing that? Does Oracle have a size specification for BLOB columns?

Comment: can you reconstruct my code for that ExecuteReader and ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: Yeah, but in Oracle, you don't specify the BLOB column size. It is not possible to set a size.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of both `ExecuteReader` and `ExecuteNonQuery` on the web already. That's not central to the issue either. At least, I don't think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved!

I just recreated my command. I no longer use a stored procedure from this insertion of image. thanks guys!

Comment: If you have solved your problem. You can delete this answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).